# How do I loop through an ionic select value from 1 to a number from the api?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on this ionic app and I was wondering how can I loop from 1 to 56(Value from the api).

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="pax">
    <ion-option value="{{index}}" *ngFor="let index of [0,1,2,3,4,5]">      
    {{index}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

This works but when I change the `*ngFor` to `let index of [1..book.pages]`, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ngFor` can be used to repeat items for any iterable object. Here `[1..book.pages]` is not an array. You also seems to be wrongly using the  spread operator `...`. Instead, for looping through a range of number, create an array dynamically and than use it in `*ngFor` directive.

Furthermore, `value="{{index}}"` is incorrect. There is no need to use string interpolation `{{ }}` within the HTML Tags.

Following code might guide you:

in some.component.ts

```
  value = getValueFromApi();
  pages = new Array(this.value);
  constructor(){
    for (let index = 0; index < this.pages.length; index++) {
      //any custom logic
      this.pages[index] = index;    
    }
```

in some.component.html

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="anyModel" *ngFor="let index of pages">
   <ion-option value="index"> {{index}} </ion-option>  
</ion-select>
```

It has nothing to do with ionic, please update it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`[1..xxx]` isn't valid in TypeScript or Angular template syntax (at least as far as I know and have tested out). You can create a function on your component and use your favorite method in TypeScript to create such an array (or even create a pipe that does it if you need to use it across components).

Here is one example:

```html
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="pax">
    <ion-option value="{{index}}" *ngFor="let index of getOptions(book.pages)">      
    {{index}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

```js
getOptions(num: number) {
    return Array.from({length: num}, (v, k) => k + 1);
}
```